# yahoo finance api issue with gold price

Tags: jquery, api, yahoo-finance

the problem  with yahoo finance api the prices is wrong as XAU/SAR or SAR/XAU

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fe%3D.csv%26f%3Dnl1d1t1%26s%3Dsarxau%3DX%22%3B&format=json&callback=
```

it returns 344 sar it should be return 4961.89 sar .i want solution for this is it internal problem with yahoo or with my code

Comment: Why do you say it should be 4961.89 car? Here (http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=SARXAU=X) it is 352.0811

Comment: look here it was return the that value until today http://www.xe.com/ar/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=XAU&To=SAR